# How to place a clickable icon behind banner image?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```html
<div align="center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x44" width="100%" height="44">
  <div align="right">
    <a href="fb.com/mypage"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x22" width="22" height="20"></a>
    <div align="right">
      <a href="twitter.com/mypage"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x22" width="22" height="20"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which looks like:

[image: http://i65.tinypic.com/15fmwia.jpg]

But in my achievement I like it to look like this image:

[image: http://i65.tinypic.com/34ez5o2.jpg]

Please can any one give me simple css code for this?

Comment: I made you a snippet. It shows invalid HTML. Please correct it

Comment: i cant figure out any error as it is in example please can explain saying

Comment: You have no closing /divs and the two link divs are not chidlren of the banner div nor positioned absolutely or floated

Comment: please do you mean i can't achieve my expected result with my stated example? Am new here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844207/how-to-make-a-div-to-wrap-two-float-divs-inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.**

You can use `position:absolute` to right align your images. Just remember to set `position:relative` to your parent element.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.right img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x44" width="100%" height="44">
  <div class="right">
    <a href="fb.com/mypage"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x22" width="22" height="20"></a>
    <a href="twitter.com/mypage"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x22" width="22" height="20"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```